# Windows 10 firewall block all external traffic and allow local one

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, windows-firewall

This is probably a noob question:

I want to block all the outbound external traffic (public internet) but still allow all the internal traffic (from the local net). What I tried is:

- Allow outbound connections that do not match a rule.
- Added a new rule that matches all programs, services, protocols, **remote IP addresses** and the local IP address 1.1.1.1 (since I have to enter at least one).

If instead of matching that IP address I match any address, then the rule effectively blocks everything (including local traffic). But with my approach, the rule stops working and all traffic (including external one) is allowed.

I don't understand why making the rule to match a subset of local IP addresses causes the rule to stop working.

Thanks!

Comment: The only way I know how to implement what you describe with Windows Firewall would be to use a proxy.  This would allow you to create a single deny rule for the proxy, thus allowing you to create an allow rule for all internal traffic.  **What you really need is a hardware solution, which allows you to deny all traffic, that is outside of your internal network.**

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I would like to understand why this approach doesn't work. And why the firewall shows this behaviour when I filter by IP.